# specify target RPM version for rpmbuild

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

Is there a way to specify the version of the RPM generated by rpmbuild?

For example:
On a machine with RPM version 4.8.0 , I would like to be able to generate rpm files suitable for deployment on a box running RPM version 4.4.2.3, as well as rpm files suitable for deployment on RPM version 4.8.0

I need to do this for legacy reasons - currently I need a dedicated legacy build box with RPM version 4.4.2.3.

TY

Answer (score 1):

1) If you build package using some recent rpm, it can be deployed on system with older system without problem. E.g. packages build on Fedora 23 can be deployed on RHEL 7 (you need to make sure the macros are expanded correctly, if you are calling rpmbuild directly, but that can be solved by my next point).

2) you you build using `mock` then it will create chroot and it will using rpmbuild from that chroot. So on Fedora 23 the command `mock -r epel-6-x86_64 foo.src.rpm` will build the package with rpmbuild from Centos/RHEL 6.

Comment: regarding 1) -  a 4.8 rmp gives errors on a box with rpm version 4.4.2.3, but I will look into point 2 ty

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mock` or a VM/Container running the target OS version.